# Find minimum of $\frac{a+3c}{a+2b+c}+\frac{7a+6b+3c}{a+b+2c}+\frac{c-a}{2a+b+c}$ for non-negative reals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

> Let $a, b, c\ge 0$, not all zero. Find the minimum of
> $$N = \frac{a+3c}{a+2b+c}+\frac{7a+6b+3c}{a+b+2c}+\frac{c-a}{2a+b+c}. $$

Comment: if one let $A=2a+b+c$, $B=a+2b+c$, and $C=a+b+2c$, the original equation could be written as $ N=\frac{2C}{B}+\frac{3A+2B}{C}+\frac{C}{A}-3$. And, then...

Comment: Can you find $A,B,C$ minimizing your expression?

Comment: Revised: $a,b,c\in R^+$, and $a+2b+c\neq 0$, $a+b+2c\neq 0$, and $2a+b+c\neq 0$.

Comment: Now, by using AM-GM, $ \frac{2C}{B}+\frac{2B}{C}\geq 2 \sqrt{2\times 2} \equiv 4 $, $ \frac{3A}{C}+\frac{C}{A}\geq 2 \sqrt{3\times 1} \equiv 2\sqrt{3}$. Equality holds when $\frac{C}{B}=\frac{B}{C}$ and $\frac{3A}{C}=\frac{C}{A}$. In other words, $N\geq 4+2\sqrt{3}-3=1+2\sqrt{3}$, when $B=C=\sqrt{3} A$.

Comment: That sounds like an answer. If you work out the details, feel free to add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

(This initial part is not a solution. It is too long to be a comment. This demonstrates that the suggested approach of substituting the denominator doesn't work out because equality is not achieved as the condition $ a \geq 0$ is not met.)

We use the substitution $x = a + 2b + c, y = a+b+2c, z = 2a + b + c$.

This system gives us $ a = (-x-y+3z)/4, b = (3x-y-z)/4, c = (-x+3y-z)/4$.

The expression becomes:
$$\frac{ -x + 2y } { x} + \frac{ 2 x - y + 3z } { y} + \frac{ y - z  } { z} = \frac{ 2y}{x} + \frac{ 2x}{y} + \frac{3z}{y} + \frac{ y}{z}  -3. $$

Since $ \frac{ 2y}{x} + \frac{ 2x}{y} \geq 2\sqrt{4} = 4$ and $ \frac{ 3z}{y} + \frac{y}{z} \geq 2 \sqrt{3} $, hence a lower bound is $ 2 \sqrt{3} +1 \approx 4.46 $.

Equality is achieved when $ y = x,  y = \sqrt{3} z$, or equivalently when
$ a : b : c = 3 - 2 \sqrt{3} : 2 \sqrt{3} -1 : 2 \sqrt{3} - 1 $, which we have to verify have the same sign.

However, they do not have the same sign, so equality CANNOT be achieved. The minimum, or infimum, is higher.

We need the extra condition that (symmetric) $3z  \geq x + y$ in order to get (symmetric) $a \geq 0$.
This condition was violated when we tried to find the equality case.

---

Since the expression is symmetric, WLOG we may assume that $ y = 1$. If so, we want to minimize

$$ \frac{2}{x} + 2x + 3z + \frac{1}{z} - 3 $$

subject to $3z \geq x + 1, 3 \geq x + z, 3x \geq z + 1$.

Even doing Lagrangian, this is horrendous and has very ugly solutions. We can show that the minimum happens on the boundary $3z=x+1$, but the actual solution ($\approx 4.493$) is pretty ugly.

I'm doubtful there's a contest-math solution.
My guess is that the problem setters made a mistake by not checking $ a : b : c$.
I do wish there was a nice way to complete this problem though, since it would illustrate the importance of checking conditions instead of just assuming as most of us did.

Comment: Nice. I think the minimum occurs when one of $a, b, c$ is zero.

Comment: @River Right, when $3z = x+y$, then $a=0$.

Comment: Nice, so we can solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @RiverLi Actually, I made a logical error. I can't just reduce $z \rightarrow z'$

Comment: Can it be overcome?

Comment: @RiverLi I've been trying, but nothing has worked out (in part because of how ugly the solutions are, there's going to be a ton of work involved). Not all inequality questions have a nice solution.

Comment: If we fix $z$, then $f$ is strictly decreasing on $x < 1$ and strictly increasing on $x > 1$. So we can split the constraints e.g. we can express the constraints as $1\le z \le 2$ and $(z + 1)/3 \le x \le 3 - z$, OR, $1/2 \le z \le 1$ and $(z + 1)/3 \le x \le 3z + 1$, we can split it more.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x,y,z$ be the denominators of the three fractions, and express $a,b,c$ in terms of $x,y,z$. Then write $N$ in terms of $x,y,z$. After some simplification we will get terms like $\frac{x}{z},\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{x},\frac{y}{z},\cdots$Then consider inequality $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\geqslant2$ if $xy$ is positive and analogously $\frac{x}{z}+\frac{z}{x}\geqslant2$ and so on...

Comment: River Li points out that equality cannot be achieved for positive $a, b, c$. I've added details.