# Find minimum of ${(a+3c)\over(a+2b+c)} + {4b\over(a+b+2c)} - {8c\over(a+b+3c)}$ for non-negative reals

Tags: inequality, optimization

> Let $a, b, c \ge 0$, not all zero. Find the minimum value of $${(a+3c)\over(a+2b+c)} + {4b\over(a+b+2c)} - {8c\over(a+b+3c)}.$$

Here was my attempt:

If c tends to infinity and a and b are small we get 1/3.

Now , i took $b=0$ and we get $(a-c)^2\over(a+c)(a+3c)$ clearly at $a=c$ this is $0$. And hence i can conclude that the infimum is $0$. This looked optimal.

But I took $a=1, b=3, c=10$ where the result is negative.

I don't see any definitve approach to this problem now. Hence, requesting your help !

Comment: use same idea as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351976/finding-the-minimum-of-n-fraca3ca2bc-frac7a6b3cab2c

Comment: Looks like the minimum is when you have some terrible numbers for $a,b,c$, resulting in $12\sqrt2-17$. Doubt if the kind of AM-GM in the link referred to above will get that. Where did you get this problem, BTW?

Comment: @Macavity When $a = \sqrt{2} - 1, b = 1, c = 2 + \sqrt{2}$, $f = 12\sqrt{2} - 17$. One may use derivatives. Hope to see nice solutions (e.g., without derivatives or using AM-GM etc).

Comment: @Macavity It (should) work out. Let me verify that ...

Comment: @CalvinLin Setting a variable to say $1$ is easy, so this is a two variable problem.  However guessing an answer like the one above, then using appropriate AM-GMs is clearly working backwards and does not seem a generally useful approach - still may be interesting to see.

Comment: @Macavity Solution added. I think our wires crossed, what did you mean by "if the kind of AM-GM in the link ..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Albus mentioned, we use the substitution:
$ x = a + 2b + c, y = a + b + 2c, z = a + b + 3c$.

This system gives us $ a = -x  + 5y - 3z, b = x - 2y + z, c = 0x - y + z$.

The expression becomes:
$$\frac{ -x + 2y } { x} + \frac{ 4 x - 8 y + 4z } { y} + \frac{ 8y - 8z  } { z} = \frac{ 2y}{x} + \frac{ 4x}{y} + \frac{4z}{y} + \frac{ 8y}{z}  -17. $$

Since $ \frac{ 2y}{x} + \frac{ 4x}{y} \geq 2\sqrt{8} = 4 \sqrt{2}$ and $ \frac{ 4z}{y} + \frac{8y}{z} \geq 2 \sqrt{32} = 8 \sqrt{2}$, hence a lower bound is $ 12 \sqrt{2} - 17 \approx -0.0294$.

Equality is achieved when $ y = \sqrt{2} x,  z = \sqrt{2} y$, or equivalently when
$ a : b : c = 5\sqrt{2} - 7 : 3 - 2 \sqrt{2} : 2 - \sqrt{2} $, which we have to verify have the same sign (If not, that can't be achieved.)

Comment: Your solution is better than mine.

Comment: A nice thing is: Actually, there are some constraints on $x, y, z$ from $a, b, c \ge 0$. However, the constraints are satisfied when applying AM-GM.

Comment: @RiverLi This is a common enough trick (like Albus pointed out). The problem is very contrived, like requiring all of denominators to only use $+ $ signs, (also if there's a $-$ sign, then the denominator could be 0), and that the "cross-term" has to be non-negative. Knowing this trick, it's obvious how they constructed the problem. Without it, it's hard to deconstruct it. I'm impressed with how you pushed through it.

Comment: Nice. The question in the link (Albus pointed out) seems different? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351976/find-minimum-of-fraca3ca2bc-frac7a6b3cab2c-fracc-a2abc

Comment: @RiverLi Right, that's why it's "use same idea", namely "use the substitution as given by the denominator", which was what I did.

Comment: Suggestion: You said "hence the minimum is ...", I think at this moment, you can only say a lower bound is $12\sqrt{2} - 17$. You should add something (e.g. is attained) before saying that.

Comment: Actually, by 'different I mean in that question, it seems that the constraints are not met when applying AM-GM. You may try that question.

Comment: @RiverLi Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, for that problem, my guess is that the problem setters made a mistake by not checking $ a : b : c$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is a nice and simple approach!